# I want to remove some portion of video in regular intervals

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, windows-8.1

I have 22 minutes and 21 second video. I want to remove some portion of video in regular intervals. Like for every 30 seconds I need to remove next 5 seconds and then after 30 seconds again I need to remove the next 5 seconds.

How do I do this in ffmpeg?

I tried this code

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(t\,30)\,5),setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -af "aselect=not(mod(t\,30)\,5),asetpts=N/SR/TB" output.mp4
```

getting error like this :

```
[Parsed_select_0 @ 000001df33cd8e40] Error while parsing expression 'not(mod(t,30),5)'
[AVFilterGraph @ 000001df339f6740] Error initializing filter 'select' with args 'not(mod(t,30),5)'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: did you try a 3-line script with splitting into images, deleting and re-encoding?

Comment: how to do it . I tried above code